# Borland C++. Помогите с кодом для отправки сообщений на email

Tags: c++, borland-c++

Всем привет!
У меня есть код:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
        IdMessage1->From->Text = "serv3rb@yandex.ru";

    IdMessage1->Recipients->EMailAddresses = "serv3rb@yandex.ru";

    IdMessage1->Subject = "serv3rb@yandex.ru";

    IdMessage1->Body->Text = "123";

    IdSMTP1->Connect();

    if (IdSMTP1->Connected())

    IdSMTP1->Send(IdMessage1);

    else

    IdSMTP1->Disconnect();
}
```

Компилятор ругается:

```
E2451: Undefined Symbol 'IdMessage1'
```

Не задавайте вопросы по типу "А где инициализация?" Я её задал в начале. Вот:

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
        IdSMTP1->Host = "smtp.yandex.ru";
        IdSMTP1->Port = 25;

        IdSMTP1->UserId = "serv3rb@yandex.ru";

        IdSMTP1->Password = "***";
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не могу найти в Borland IDMessage1. В какой вкладке он находится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет поля `IdMessage1`. Откройте хидер и объявите его `TIdMessage * IdMessage1;`. В конструкторе инициализируйте `IdMessage1 = new TIdMessage(this);`

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо!!!!!